# Can't get Python working on Macbook Pro with M1 Max Chip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read all the similar questions and things still aren't working for me.  I think things may be messed up "under the hood".  I would love to have a completely clean install of Python that I could then manage in environments.  I've followed videos and nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone have a sure-fire, ELI5-type clean and install procedure that I can follow?  My latest issue is that homebrew won't even install it.  I get the following:

```
> brew install python
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
(base) greg@greg-mbp ~ % where python3
/Users/greg/miniforge3/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
(base) grega@grega-mbp ~ % brew install python3
Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
"Alternative Installs" from:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
  brew bundle dump
```

I tried following those instructions but nothing seems to be working.  I installed Anaconda and that would only launch from the command line and not the icon.  I'd like to be able to get this working so I can use both Anaconda (for Jupyter Notebook) and Dataspell as an IDE with different versions of Python so I can make sure packages (data science packages, FBprophet, etc.) work in the correct versions.

I also tried following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Acht_5_HTo) on installing with miniforge.  When I do that, I get Python 3.9.6 installed.  I created a version for 3.10 by entering:

```
conda create -n py310
conda activate py310
conda install python=3.10
```

When I do that and then run `python --version` it still reports 3.9.6.  Running `which python` returns `python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3`

Thanks so much for any help.  This is driving me crazy.

***Current Profiles per question below***

.bash_profile:

`export PATH="/usr/local/arm-homebrew/bin:$PATH"`

.zshrc:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/grega/miniforge3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/grega/miniforge3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/grega/miniforge3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/grega/miniforge3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

alias python=/usr/bin/python3
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: What happens when you try [removing](https://superuser.com/questions/786956/how-to-remove-zsh-alias) the `python` alias?

Comment: I cleared out my .bash_profile as well as .zshrc and neither worked.  I reset both, so now they're updated.  I edited my profiles and included above.

Comment: I've added an answer to someone with the same question elsewhere on this site describing how to install Python with [Nix](https://nixos.org/). Nix is not exactly a toolchain intended for 5-year-olds (it's very concept-heavy if you want to be able to leverage its full power, in much the same way that git expects users to know more concepts than svn does to use the tool well), but it's an extremely _effective_ one; great security model, solid focus on reproducibility, &c.

Comment: BTW, notice how `miniforge` is first in your PATH. If it comes before any homebrew-managed paths, well, there you are. (That said, I really don't recommend Homebrew be used, ever, by anyone; the "we're just going to allow non-root users write access to a place where executables live" design decision is one I consider outright indefensible).

Comment: And yes, the alias does mean your PATH is irrelevant, so you need to kill the alias _before_ you do anything PATH-related. But if you go the nix route you'll be able to throw out both miniforge and Homebrew -- it replaces both those tools entirely; you still need to delete the alias either way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks so much!  commenting out those aliases did the trick.  I will also look into Nix.  I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: @fakedad, thanks very much.  I wasn't sure what you initially meant but removing the alias fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alias python=/usr/bin/python3` causes any invocation of `python` at the interactive shell to be replaced with `/usr/bin/python3`. This forces a specific copy of Python (provided by Apple) to be used instead of the one provided by Miniforge or Homebrew.

Delete that alias (starting a new shell after modifying the configuration files, or using `unalias python` to remove it from a live shell), and then the first instance of `python` found while traversing your PATH will be used instead.